# Como imprimir uma página diretamente, sem caixa de diálogo do navegador, usando Javascript?

Tags: javascript, impressão

Como imprimir, isto é, enviar uma página diretamente para impressão física, sem exibir a caixa de diálogo do navegador antes?

Vejo muitos exemplos na internet mas todos pedem confirmação de impressão.

Comment: Sem caixa de diálogo do navegador você quis dizer?

Comment: isso mesmo sem esse dialogo que o navegador mostra

Comment: Acho difícil, você terá que encontrar uma forma de enviar o documento direto pra impressora. Não sei se é possível fazer isso com JS.

Comment: voce sabe outras formas?

Comment: Não sei se é possível fazer isso, isso é quase a mesma coisa de que você querer tirar foto com a webcam do usuário sem que ele perceba ou sem precisar da autorização

Comment: Tem como enviar o comando ok? pelo java script?
por que ele carregando o Popup e confirmando o ok! nao seria problema.

Comment: Boa noite, a caixa de dialogo serve para configurar a impressão e selecionar o dispositivo, portanto não vejo por que não ter ela. Para ser mais direto na API do JavaScript não existe tal opção, o que você pode fazer é criar o seu próprio navegador usando Chromium ou WebkitGTK e forçar o software pegar a primeira impressora que encontrar.

Comment: Essa ação fere normas básicas de segurança e privacidade.. todos os browsers homologados bloqueiam por padrão a menos que o usuário remova o bloqueio.

Answer (score 2):

Somente com Javascript, **não é possível**. Se fosse, seria uma grande falha de segurança, imagine você visitando um site qualquer e do nada a sua impressora dispara imprimindo várias folhas sem a sua permissão?

Talvez seja possível por meio do desenvolvimento alguma extensão, mas isso é assunto para outra pergunta.

A nível de conhecimento, no Firefox você pode fazer algumas modificações que permitem imprimir um documento sem o *prompt* de confirmação da seguinte forma:

- Digite `about:config` para entrar na aba de configurações (clique em "serei cuidadoso, prometo") e prossiga.
- Crie uma nova preferência do tipo booleano. Dê o nome de `print.always_print_silent` e marque-a como `true`.

Ao reiniciar o navegador, qualquer chamada via Javascript com código `window.print()` iniciará a impressão automaticamente. Assim, até mesmo um link como o abaixo funcionará:

```
<a href='javascript:window.print()'>Imprimir essa página</a>
```

Mas como pode ver de qualquer maneira é necessária a permissão por parte do usuário.

---

<sub>**ps:** Caso tenha feito o teste acima, não esqueça de entrar novamente na aba de preferências do Firefox e alterar a chave `print.always_print_silent` para `false` (ou então clicar em "restaurar o padrão").</sub>

Comment: "seria uma grande falha de segurança, imagine você visitando um site qualquer e do nada a sua impressora dispara imprimindo várias folhas sem a sua permissão" Boa observação

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei uma "solução" no SO.en, como não tenho impressora em casa não tem como testar, mas fique a vontade para testar e nos dizer se funcionou.

## [Resposta em Inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1124848/3497987)

---

(Tradução Livre)

> Eu não encontrei solução para outros navegadores. Quando eu postei essa questão, IE era a maior prioridade e felizmente eu encontrei uma para ele. Se você tem uma solução para outros navegadores (firefox, safari, opera) por favor, compartilhe aqui. Obrigado.

```
<script language='VBScript'>
Sub Print()
       OLECMDID_PRINT = 6
       OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER = 2
       OLECMDEXECOPT_PROMPTUSER = 1
       call WB.ExecWB(OLECMDID_PRINT, OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER,1)
End Sub
document.write "<object ID='WB' WIDTH=0 HEIGHT=0 CLASSID='CLSID:8856F961-340A-11D0-A96B-00C04FD705A2'></object>"
</script>
```

Agora chame:

```
<a href="javascript:window.print();">Print</a>
```

Enviará a impressão sem a janela de impressão ser aberta.

---

Consulte a página da **[PERGUNTA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096862/print-directly-from-browser-without-print-popup-window)**, lá tem muitas resposta, algumas realmente interessante que vale a pena testar, como por exemplo [essa solução para o Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13965010/3497987), que não sei se realmente funciona.

Comment: vb script ?? estou no projeto .net mvc e usando java script!! tem como fazer isso??

Comment: @HansMiller seu projeto é utilizando HTML ou é puro Javascript?

Comment: Html !! Java script soh o comando para imprimir!!

Comment: Então você vai colocar esse código da mesma forma que coloca o javascript, só que coloca esse código no início do head do teu HTML, antes dos javascript, acredito que ele sobrescreve a função de impressão ou algo parecido. Já até tem a tag `script` ali pra auxiliar, que no caso é a mesma tag pra javascript só que está especificando que é VB no parâmetro. @HansMiller

Comment: @HansMiller, apesar da resposta do Kadu ser muito boa, temos que atentar que ela faz uso do ActiveX, recurso que a Microsoft abandonou no MS Edge, quanto a FF, Chrome e Opera, você pode fazer um plugin NPAPI que irá funcionar nas versões antigas. preciso nem dizer que tanto o ActiveX e o NPAPI trazem vunerabilidades graves, então a opção mais segura é desevolver uma app para o chome e fazer uso das api de [usb](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/usb), [serial](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/serial), [printerProvider](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/printerProvider), etc.